# MySql - How to auto delete a specific row from table

Tags: mysql

In my website user can choose how long his post can display in home page, after a certain time I want to delete that post automatically.

By using Event scheduler in MySql, I could only able to delete a couple of records which are stored more than the specified time. But I want to delete a specific row within a user specified time.

Ex:

user1 - posted - delete after 1hr
user2 - posted - delete after 5hrs

Could some one tell me how to do this?

Comment: You can create a `ScheduleDeletePosts` table with `(PostID, WhenToBeDeleted)` columns and a recurring event that runs every minute and checks that table. If the time has passed, it deletes the post (and the respecting row from the schedule table).

Comment: To clarify: I meant one event for everything. Not one event per post.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Could you give an example?

Comment: This is a variation on the same thing I'm saying but using a separate table rather than a column in the existing table.  Split your logic so that you're pre-calculating the removal time and storing it in the database.  The DB then just has to do a simple check against that time.  It is simpler, more performant, and more in-line with the Rule of Representation than trying to handle this at removal time.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- Delete it using app code with more fine grained queries
- Set a date when the record is created for the time when
  the post should be    deleted and then use that in the event
  scheduler predicate

Comment: How I can delete the post even if I set the date? or should I create an event for every post??

Comment: You should set the date to the (then) future time when the post should be deleted calculated off of the per user preference (different from the creation timestamp).  A single event can then delete all records where that field is a date in the past.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

create a event and call a stored procedure which will check what users have defined their time limit to delete the post

Comment: I understand that I have to create a new event for every user post. Am I right?

Comment: no ,create a event which will execute in each 5-10 min (or a high number like a day ) and will check through procedure that any post is there to delete based on user time limit.